# Working with union types best approach when using primitive or interface type

Tags: typescript, union-types

So I'm trying to create a date model that can be range date or a single day date (primitive)

```
export interface DateRange {
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  shortcut?: string;
}

private selectedSate:DateRange | string = null;
```

but it seems TypesScript doesn't like it when I try to access a property when the `selectedSate` is an object:

```
80:65 Property 'start' does not exist on type 'string | DateRange'.
  Property 'start' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I'm aware of using the "if" wrapper anywhere I access it with:
`if (typeof this.datePicker !== 'string')`  check, but I want to avoid it since I'm accessing it many times in my code [(docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types).

What is the best approach when union members can be either objects or primitives?

---

The model can be changed during runtime to one of the union types. But I'm trying to avoid type check on the model before property access (in the case of `DateRange` interface). Is this possible?

Comment: TS compiler is right, DateRange is an object and string is a string. If you don't put the relevant checks you might run into issues in runtime.

Comment: What if you use something like this `type SelectedState<T extends DateRange | string> = T;` and then do `const selectedSate: SelectedState<string> = "";`

Comment: The use of generics makes it a lot cleaner, so you can avoid the if statements. Another solution is to use `as` keyword. `const selected = null as DateRange;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just use unions:

```js
interface DateRangeObject {
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  shortcut?: string;
}

type DateRangePrimitive = string | null;

type DateRange = DateRangeObject | DateRangePrimitive

const selectedSate: DateRange = null; // ok
const selectedSate_: DateRange = 'hello'; // ok
const selectedSate__: DateRange = {
  start: new Date(),
  end: new Date(),
  shortcut: 'ua',
}; // ok

const selectedSate___: DateRange = 1; // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gJTiA5hAeQCMArCBMZAbwChlkBnMOKMALjQwgG47kIQAEw7pIvegwAWAe1YIArmAD8HJlFC5eAXxo0wATwAOKURGx4IABXUBbYGGAA3FAF5GYdXmQAfZCHkANgG8ekYmXOb4yG6mkYSk5JS%20sTj41sB2Ds66CNIgTIwQAYkQggDKXCIRqa5%20gcHIAPSNyNIA1jS5%20ZQMRSXlXAD6VVg10cgA5JJFAdIT3E0t7Z15Bb3FFKUVkIPDnKMW47QSzKwcIBAA7vsQABQAlAA0fALCflc3D88SMnKKHBN5HAJs8tAtmq0OituoUNpABjtdiMzGM3ABGcEtCAAD2Mm0E-CgUFkNCAA)

Comment: Thanks but this is not help me when the model can be change during runtime.
For example:`selectedSate_` change after clickEvent to be just like `selectedSate__` and then I try to access `.shortcut` for example.

Comment: [Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=5&pln=18&pc=18#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gJTiA5hAeQCMArCBMZAbwChlkBnMOKMALjQwgG47kIQAEw7pIvegwAWAe1YIArmAD8HJlFC5eAXxo0wATwAOKURGx4IABXUBbYGGAA3FAF5GYdXmQAfZCHkANgG8ekYmXOb4yG6mkYSk5JS+sTj41sB2Ds66CNIgTIwQAYkQggDKXCIRqa5+gcHIAPSNyNIA1jS5+ZQMRSXlXAD6g1VYNdHUfEws7H4QAO6ckAAUAJQANHwCwnOLpmubEjJyihwA5PJwZ5ta3E0t7brFPX0UpRWQI0tm425nkkUAtIzncaM0-NJFs9GHB9IxpDYUBBnOBkAhJONesU3gNPsgwNJkEQUCR5AUAsA2igsf0PhBhjRgDBljScXTBgA6KSyMAKMCrWgSV6QXH0rnMVgTEALb5rbS6IA)

Comment: Pls share full example, I believe we can figure smth out

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you get: having a union type makes the compiler allow only properties that are *common for all members of the union*. Since literal strings cannot have custom properties, the `start` property cannot be accessed. As per [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#defining-a-union-type):

> TypeScript will only allow you to do things with the union if that thing is valid for every member of the union.

You need to let the compiler know somehow that you expect the union to be [*narrowed*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to one of its members. The most obvious solution that you are already aware of is to use a type guard (either with `typeof`/`instanceof` or a user-defined one).

The second one is to just let the [*control flow analysis*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) do its job exactly like [captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68329717/11407695) shows. The issue with it that you pointed out is actually a useful heuristics the compiler uses to narrow down types: *initialization of a variable of a union type narrows it to the type of the assigned value*.

In the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gJTiA5hAeQCMArCBMZAbwChlkBnMOKMALjQwgG47kIQAEw7pIvegwAWAe1YIArmAD8HJlFC5eAXxo0wATwAOKURGx4IABXUBbYGGAA3FAF5GYdXmQAfZCHkANgG8ekYmXOb4yG6mkYSk5JS%20sTj41sB2Ds66CNIgTIwQAYkQggDKXCIRqa5%20gcHIAPSNyNIA1jS5%20ZQMRSXlXAD6g1VYNdHUfEws7H4QAO6ckAAUAJQANHwCwnOLpmubEjJyihwA5PJwZ5ta3E0t7brFPX0UpRWQI0tm425nkkUAtIznddM1noVim8Bp9VB4NDRelDIDCIIMwS0QNJFhCGHB9IxpDYUBBnOBkAhJOMkf0PmjkGBpMgiCgSPICgFgG0UDToXThjRgDBlryUfyAHRSWRgBRgVa0CSvMVDSXMVgTEALb5rbS6IA) you linked, the type of `selectedSate_` *after* initialization to `'hello'` is `string`, therefore, no access to `DateRange` properties down the flow. The compiler is smart enough, though, to remember that the declaration is mutable (`let`), so if you do this:

```js
selectedSate_ = { start: new Date(), end: new Date(), shortcut: "test" };

if(selectedSate_.shortcut){ //OK
  selectedSate_.start = new Date(); //Ok
}
```

the control flow analysis will do its job and understand that the `selectedSate_` is now of type `DateRange`. If, however, the type can "change during runtime" any time, TypeScript can't help you: you will either have to guard or make a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

If you think about it, this is actually a *good thing*, because if the type can arbitrarily change at runtime, there is *no guarantee* at compile-time that the variable is of a certain type (unless you either shut TypeScript up [type assertion route] or do the right thing [type guard]).